# Is there a way to see the component parts that make up your reputation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, api

For example:

You have gained X reputation from upvoted answers.
You have lost Y reputation from downvoted answers.
You have gained Z reputation from accepted answers.

Even better might be to see which tags have generated reputation for yourself (or even other users).  This would be a great way to be able to quickly tell how much authority on a given subject someone has.  For example, if someone is answering my jQuery question, and they have > 10k rep, but < 100 of it is from answering/asking questions tagged with jQuery, that would be useful info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [reputation audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation) tells you how it is made up of individual parts, but doesn't give overall figures. You should be able to write a script to do that, though.

Comment: This is cool!  What do the code numbers on the far left mean though?

Comment: @Ender: They're the VoteTypeId. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump/2678#2678).